# Input field are not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, forms, mobile

On my page I have two forms (both on front page)

Everything is working great on laptop browsers, but I can't text anything in the input fields  on mobile devices. As you can see, the input fields are showing and I'm therefor assuming this has something to do with css. But I'm not sure.

The site is here: https://fairbenzin.dk

I added the code to down below.

Thank in advance.

```js
 
        getPrice = function() {
            var b_rabat1 = 166;
            var b_rabat2 = 167;
            var b_rabat3 = 168;
            var b_rabat4 = 170;
            var d_rabat1 = 176;
            var d_rabat2 = 177;
            var d_rabat3 = 179;
            var d_rabat4 = 182;
            var benzinpris = 10;
            var dieselpris = 9;
            var antalkm = 15; 
            var totalbenzinbefore = 0;
            var totaldieselbefore = 0;
            var resultprocentbenzin = 0;
            var resultprocentdiesel = 0;
            var numVal1 = (Number(document.getElementById("antal_km_total").value) / antalkm);
            //BENZINUDREGNING
            var bresult = 0
                totalbenzinbefore = (benzinpris * numVal1);
                if (numVal1 <= 10000) {
                bresult = ((b_rabat1 * numVal1) / 100);
                resultprocentbenzin = ((bresult/totalbenzinbefore) * 100);
                }
                else if (numVal1 > 10000 && numVal1 <= 50000) {
                bresult = ((b_rabat2 * numVal1) / 100);
                resultprocentbenzin = ((bresult/totalbenzinbefore) * 100);
                }
                else if (numVal1 > 50000 && numVal1 <= 100000) {
                bresult = ((b_rabat3 * numVal1) / 100);
                resultprocentbenzin = ((bresult/totalbenzinbefore) * 100);
                }
                else if (numVal1 > 100000 && numVal1 <= 200000) {
                bresult = ((b_rabat4 * numVal1) / 100);
                resultprocentbenzin = ((bresult/totalbenzinbefore) * 100);
                }
                else {
                bresult = 18;
                resultprocentbenzin = 18;
                }
            //DIESELUDREGNING
            var dresult = 0
                totaldieselbefore = (dieselpris * numVal1)
                if (numVal1 <= 10000) {
                dresult = ((d_rabat1 * numVal1) / 100);
                resultprocentdiesel = ((dresult/totaldieselbefore) * 100);
                }
                else if (numVal1 > 10000 && numVal1 <= 50000) {
                dresult = ((d_rabat2 * numVal1) / 100);
                resultprocentdiesel = ((dresult/totaldieselbefore) * 100);
                }
                else if (numVal1 > 50000 && numVal1 <= 100000) {
                dresult = ((d_rabat3 * numVal1) / 100);
                resultprocentdiesel = ((dresult/totaldieselbefore) * 100);
                }
                else if (numVal1 > 100000 && numVal1 <= 200000) {
                dresult = ((d_rabat4 * numVal1) / 100);
                resultprocentdiesel = ((dresult/totaldieselbefore) * 100);
                }
                else {
                dresult = 18;
                resultprocentdiesel = 18;
                }
            document.getElementById("total").value = bresult.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("besparelse").value = resultprocentbenzin.toFixed(1);
            document.getElementById("total2").value = dresult.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("besparelse2").value = resultprocentdiesel.toFixed(1);
        }
```

```css
<style>
#calculator p {
 font-size: 0.840rem;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.kategori{
font-weight: bold;
}
.disclaimer{
text-align: center;
padding: 2%;
background-color: #eeeeee!important;
border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<div id="calculator">
<h2>Brændstofberegner</h2>
    <p>Hvor mange km. kører du om året i alt?</p>
    <input id="antal_km_total" type="tel">
    <input onclick="getPrice()" type="submit" value="Beregn rabat på benzin og diesel" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit">
  <p class="kategori">Besparelse på benzin</p>
    <p>Op til kroner i besparelse</p>
    <input readonly id="total" type="tel">
    <p>Op til % besparelse</p>
    <input readonly id="besparelse" type="tel">
  <p class="kategori">Besparelse på diesel</p>
    <p>Op til kroner i besparelse</p>
    <input readonly id="total2" type="tel">
<p>Op til % besparelse</p>
    <input readonly id="besparelse2" type="tel"> 
    <p class="disclaimer">Vores beregner er baseret ud fra en standerpris på 9 DDK. pr. liter diesel, 10 DKK. pr. liter benzin og et gennemsnit på 15 km pr. liter. Vi tager forbehold for usikkerhed i beregning og besparelser skal derfor ses som vejledende. Ved et forbrug på mere end 200.000 liter brændstof fastsættes individuel rabat.</p>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: The most of the inputs are marked as read-only, you can't enter anything into those inputs in any environment. Can you please elaborate the question a bit, what exactly you want your code to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: Hi Teemu. Thanks for you answer. If you can see what it does in the provided code snippet it calculates some fuelsavings. In this script the last four input fields are readonly as this is the result fields. But I can't type anything into the first field, but only on mobile devices. That's the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, see your code working at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0378d5z/show).

Comment: Ah. It runs on my phone as well, didn't saw that. But it still dosn't run at https://fairbenzin.dk for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I saw your [website](http://farbenzine.dk/)
I got the problem

This class becomes active in mobile view
So you have to delete it or else go to css file and comment this class

`.custom-header-overlay`

Answer (score 1):

i have faced these issue also so test these input fields in HTML only .

if it's working then the back end part is completely fine  so problem will be inside the CSS or the Js , i have seen many time the front end distorted and produce a bug , we thought it's for code lol, but it's not ...
For debug purpose , print relative data in console ...it helps a lot
Thank You